# How do I specify width of infinite (AJAX loading) carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm trying to figure out how to approach this problem in the most straightforward, efficient way.

I'm building carousel that contains posts written by users. Depending on the screen size (width), number of posts shown in carousel will differ:

```
----------------------------------------
<  POST  POST  POST  POST  POST  POST  >
----------------------------------------
----------------------
<  POST  POST  POST  >
----------------------
----------
<  POST  >
----------
```

The tricky part is that I need to specify the width of the container based on the number of posts inside of it, but the number of posts is not set, and new posts will be loaded in as user scrolls the carousel.

What would be the best way to do that? Lazy way would be to give the container something like 1000000% width, the other that came to my mind is to make a jquery script that would calculate currently loaded number of loaded posts (not currently shown posts) * width of the post, and would be increasing with every click on the arrow (which triggers loading post from database script).

Since I'm not that advanced in this sort of stuff, is any of proposed above solutions good, or there are better, more efficient and more common-sense approaches to that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using media queries and calc() function together with jquery.

I added media queries for different resolutions and using calc() gave objects the width based on desired number in relation to screen width (100% width - 2*margin (60px) divided by desired number of posts):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1500px) {
    .post {
        width: calc((100% - 60px) / 6);
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
    .post {
        width: calc((100% - 50px) / 5);
    }
}
```

Next with jQuery I added simple animate function to change the margin depending on the arrow clicked, that will move the visible part of container by it's width value:

```
contentWidth = $content.outerWidth();

$buttonLeft.on('click', function() {
    $ontainer.animate({
        'margin-left' : '+=' + contentWidth
    });
});
```

This way I have flexible posts justified perfectly accurate in the container and I can carousel them with 100% accuracy. I had to add script that refresh the page on screen resize, as with this nested elements structure it was nearly impossible to make it responsive due to dynamically changing margin and posts width.